# JQuery click trigger not working on first <li> tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have **test-page.php** with code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- load bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".isi").load('button.php');
  $(".but1").click(function(){
    $("<button class='but btnNext'>before</button>").insertAfter(".but1");
  });
  $(".but2").click(function(){
    $("<a class='btn btn-primary text-white btnNext'>after</a>").insertAfter(".home");
    $("<a class='btn btn-primary text-white btnPrev'>before</a>").insertBefore(".home");
  });
  $(".but3").click(function(){
    $("<button class='but btnPrev'>after</button>").insertAfter(".but3");
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.btnNext', function(){
    $('.nav-kues .active').parent().next('li').find('.but3').trigger('click');
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="home" style="background-color:yellow">
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <div class="isi"></div>
  <div class="content">
  <p>Im Paragraph.</p>
  <ul class="nav-kues">
    <li><a class="but1">add before</a></li>
    <li><a class="but2 active">add both</a></li>
    <li><a class="but3">add after</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the **button.php** code

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">click me</a>
```

the code working fine, the button function worked as expected. the problem appear when I move the `active` class from the second `<li>` tag to the first `<li>` tag, the button is not working. I'm new in JQuery, could someone explain why is it happen?

**Edited**

Here is the not working code, the button not trigger click event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- load bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".isi").load('button.php');
  $(".but1").click(function(){
    $("<button class='but btnNext'>before</button>").insertAfter(".but1");
  });
  $(".but2").click(function(){
    $("<a class='btn btn-primary text-white btnNext'>after</a>").insertAfter(".home");
    $("<a class='btn btn-primary text-white btnPrev'>before</a>").insertBefore(".home");
  });
  $(".but3").click(function(){
    $("<button class='but btnPrev'>after</button>").insertAfter(".but3");
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.btnNext', function(){
    $('.nav-kues .active').parent().next('li').find('.but3').trigger('click');
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="home" style="background-color:yellow">
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <div class="isi"></div>
  <div class="content">
  <p>Im Paragraph.</p>
  <ul class="nav-kues">
    <li><a class="but1 active">add before</a></li>
    <li><a class="but2">add both</a></li>
    <li><a class="but3">add after</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my post and provide the not working code, the active class is on the first <li> tag and the button is not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clickhandler for `btnNext` seems overly complex and can be simplified. Since you already know the class of the button and this is the only button with that class, there is no reason to travel up and down the DOM.

```
  $('body').on('click', '.btnNext', function(){
        $('.nav-kues .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  });
```

Comment: actually, the code is more complex, I just simplified my code like that, the real code is some kind of navbar, and I need some kind of next button that trigger click event on the next <a> tag from the active class,

Comment: @marahman, I updated my answer, just change `.but3` to `a`

Comment: thanks, I just accepted this as the answer for my question. the caused of my real problem that make the button not working is because I load 2 kind of JQuery lib (v3.5.1 and v3.2.1), many thanks for the first man who comment the post, the comment is deleted once I updated the question, I forgot the username of that man.